# Batch update products programmability

Tags: woocommerce

I want to update about 3000 records by uploading a .csv file.

My code is:

```
//$arrDataForUpdate have about 3000 records...
foreach ($arrDataForUpdate as $record) {

    $product_id = 500; //for example

    $regularPrice = 20000; //for example
    $salePrice = 10000; //for example
    $stock = 8; //for example


    update_post_meta($product_id, '_regular_price', $regularPrice);
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_sale_price', $salePrice);
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_price', ($regularPrice > $salePrice) ? $regularPrice : $salePrice);

    update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', $stock);
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock_status', $stock > 0 ? 'instock' : 'outofstock');

    wc_delete_product_transients( $product_id );

}
```

Is there no better way for it?

I want an optimal way. It sends a lot of requests and queries to the database and server.

I'm worried about a **timeout** or something else.
How can I prevent or optimize it?

Comment: Stock status is not anymore a post meta data… Since Woocommerce 3, it's handled by `product_visibility` custom taxonomy, under `outofstock` term.

Comment: `_stock_status` work for me! i use latest version of woocommerce.